# 'Column' object is not callable with Regex and Pyspark

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I need to extract the integers only from url stings in the column "Page URL" and append those extracted integers to a new column. I am using PySpark. My code below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_extract

spark_df_url.withColumn("new_column", regexp_extract(col("Page URL"), "\d+", 1).show())
```

I have the following error: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable.

Comment: There must be `0`, not `1`, `.withColumn("new_column", regexp_extract("Page URL", "\d+", 0))`

Comment: Perfect! That did what I expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that's a typo, but even if the syntax was correct, the issue would still be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
spark_df_url.withColumn("new_column", regexp_extract("Page URL", "\d+", 0))
```

Specify the name of the string column as  the first argument to [`regexp_replace`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) and make sure the third argument is set to `0` as your pattern has no capturing groups and you are interested in getting the whole match value as a result.

Note that when you specified `1` as the third argument, you got empty results:

> If the regex did not match, or the specified group did not match, an empty string is returned.